# How do I have a Mediatek USB driver for Linux to flash a smart phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, linux, usb-drivers, mediatek

I am a Linux beginner, I just wanted to know how I properly download and use a "**Mediatek USB driver**".

I am using a Linux Mint MATE, and I cannot turn on the USB debugging of that phone because it was locked via FRP. When I open it and go to the settings, I cannot activate the Developer options.

I wanted to fix (or flash) phones for free, but I can't because I am not able to download the MTK USB driver, which is needed to help my PC communicate with the phone. It seems that all MTK USB drivers are perfectly fine for Windows, that's what I saw on the internet and tutorials on YouTube.

The phone I currently reviving is; **Vivo y69** with a **MT6750** chipset which suffers from **FRP lock**. I have 2 working properly with "SP flash tools" with different versions, an official auth file, a scatter file, and a DA file. I just need an MTK USB driver.

Every time I attempt to flash the phone, nothing happens. It doesn't show any lights it doesn't boot up and the progress bar on my PC does not show any changes.

I hope you can help me because I have already searched the web and downloaded different files but nothing has worked so far. I'm desperate to fix the phone(s) to give them new value.

Comment: You can't install/use Windows specific drivers/software on Linux without a compatibility layer named WINE. That can be a pain for new users. Use your package manager to search for and install software/drivers first.   Distro-maintained packages are usually easier to get working than Windows drivers through WINE.

Comment: Is "USB debugging" enabled? Otherwise, AFAIK the device cannot be detected even with [correct UDEV rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up).

Comment: If I remember correctly the leaked MTK/SP Flash tools are only available for Windows. Using flashing tools with an emulation like Wine is not recommended as it increases the chance to totally brick a device because of problems while flashing.

Comment: sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0

Comment: https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libusb-1.0-0

Comment: Update: I fixed the phone (vivo y69) via ADB but I would still try your suggestions

Comment: A bit curious how you managed to do it with ADB but USB debugging was not enabled, or was there some progress in-between?

Comment: he probably meant fastboot (not adb)

Comment: @LinuxNovice1 No need to apologize! We all have to start somewhere. I don't know much about your specific device, so I wouldn't know what to suggest. Learning more about ADB will probably be useful for years to come. Learning a bit more about Linux (devices/drivers/shell/networking/etc) will also be helpful. Learning and troubleshooting several things at the same time while trying to get stuff done can often test people's patience.